# Isolating devices within private home network

Tags: router, internet

I currently have this network setup:

[image]

As you can see, I have three devices with static ip addresses. (`192.168.1.100`, `192.168.1.123`, `192.168.1.121`) and some devices with dynamic IPs (game console etc.).

On the productivity devices I run services like [git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git), [nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) etc.

Now I want to isolate the three productivity devices from the rest of the local network:

I don't want a "private device" (red) to be able to locally communicate with a "productivity device" (purple) and vice versa.

*However* I need both (red & purple) to be able to connect to the internet.

I'd prefer to do this physically and not with software.

Would buying a separate router and connecting it like this suffice?

[image]

How would I go about configuring the routers?

Our ISP ([Swisscom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swisscom)) provided us with their [internet box](https://www.swisscom.ch/en/residential/products/internetrouter/details.html/internet-box-3-ip-11039000?payOption=ONE_TIME&useCase=ROUTERRETENTION) for us to access the internet. I'm not sure if I could replace this internet box with a generic router.

Comment: Yes, provided your router has a Network Address Translation function. It must not be a simple switch.

Comment: This is not a security question but a routing question. And it will depend on your hardware capabilities.

Comment: @schroeder I think this is very much a security question. Isolating the two clearly increases security.

Comment: The ***effect*** is security. What you are asking to do to achieve the desired effect is not. Setting up a router and a  routing table is not a security issue.

Comment: I have to disagree with you there. For example there is a post "How to securely send private keys" and similar posts on the exchange.

Comment: By that logic, many already made posts must've been migrated too. And " Setting up a router and a routing table is not a security issue." you're already presuming that I have chosen that solution, while in fact, I have not.

Comment: "I'd prefer to do this physically and not with software." -- yes, you have settled on a physical solution. That's a router or a switch. "Will connecting my chosen solution like this suffice?" That depends on how the routing or switching is configured. Configuring a route table is not a security concern.

Comment: I haven't settled on anything. I said **I'd prefer**, not **I want**.

Comment: Ok, so then let's say that the answer to your stated question ("will this suffice?") is "yes". You then ask "How would I go about configuring the routers?" Configuring a route table is not a security concern. So, you could have inferred that the answer is "yes" in that I quickly jumped to the 2nd question.

Comment: Then you could post an answer "Yes this will suffice. Asking how to configure it is a different question which you should ask on superuser."

Comment: "Yes" is insufficient as an answer to post. I skipped to the last part.

Comment: I don't think this would be "insufficient". The question is about security, not how to setup a router.

Comment: "How would I go about configuring the routers?" -- I beg to differ?

Comment: And you could still mention other means of achieving a similar effect with VLANs. As stated, I haven't ruled out a software solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127280/discussion-between-schroeder-and-marco-a).